# Multiple links in Bazinga Hateoas with Symfony

Tags: symfony, hateoas

I am using Bazinga Hateoas with Fosrest in one of my SF2 project.

In one of API call, I want to display link of friends with current user or user id supplied like this:

```html
    {
        "_links": {
            "self": { "href": "/users/1" },
            "friends": [
              { "href": "/users/2" },
              { "href": "/users/3" },
            ]
        },
    }
```

I am using below code in Entity.User.yml file:

```html
relations:
    -
      rel: self
      href:
        route: api_1_get_users
        parameters:
          id: expr(object.getId())
        absolute: true
    -  
      rel: expr(object.findFriends(object.getId()))
      href:
        route: api_1_get_users
        parameters:
          id: expr(object.getId())
        absolute: true
```

I have put "findFriends" method in repository but its not accessible inside yml file. I guess this is not the correct way of doing things.

I have gone through https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas but not able to figure out how to do it. Please guide me how I can achieve this...

Any help would be much appreciated !

Please guide me how I can achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you work with **@RelationProvider**.

```
/**
 * Note:
 * ====
 * RelationProvider takes the method name which returns the relations.
 * 
 * @Hateoas\RelationProvider("addRelations")
 */
class LinkContainingResource
{
    public function addRelations($object, ClassMetadataInterface $classMetadata)
    {
        /**
         * Important Note:
         * ===============
         * Relation is actually an Hateoas\Configuration\Relation object,
         * NOT \Hateoas\Configuration\Annotation\Relation
         */
        return [new Relation('relation_name', 'link1'),
                new Relation('relation_name', 'link2'),
                new Relation('relation_name', 'link3')];
    }
}
```

**Json/Hal Result:**

```
{
  "_links": {
    "relation_name": [
      {"href": "link1"},
      {"href": "link2"},
      {"href": "link3"}
    ]
  }
}
```